# i need a regular expression in Javascript to parse my string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

my string is 'apiName_1.0.1.yaml', i need a simple regex or string operation to get a result like below.

name - apiName
version - 1.0.1

any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the last 5 chars / the chars starting with the last dot, split the result at `_` / the last `_`, the first part is the name, the second part is the version.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: good suggestion , i was trying to do everything in regex at once.But will try this , which makes simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with the following answer using string operations only:

```js
var str = "apiName_1.0.1.yaml"
str = str.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.') // removing file extention
var [name , version] = str.split("_"); // splitting the string into name and version

console.log(name);
console.log(version);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is always a `yaml` file, try this:

```
const [, name, version] = 'apiName_1.0.1.yaml'.match(/(.*?)_(.*?)\.yaml/);
```

Nice tool to try regex with: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
[,name,version] = 'apiName_1.0.1.yaml'.match(/(.*)_([\d\.]*)\./)
console.log({name, version})
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i accepted all 3, i tried all the 3 and working fine, will use one of these as solution.

Comment: @RijuFrancis "_i accepted all 3_" You can mark only one answer as the accepted. If you accept another one, the previous will be unaccepted. Pick the one that helped you most.